# Emacs showing ^M in a process buffer

Tags: windows, emacs, character-encoding, line-endings

At the moment, I have a process-buffer which is `utf-8-auto` (emacs modeline reports the buffer as `utf-8-auto-dos`) with `CRLF` style newlines. When I write multi-line text into the buffer via a `process-send-region` or `process-send-string` each line is suffixed with `^M`.

What makes this problem odd is that text written to the process-buffer directly from the process, does not contain `^M`'s.

It doesn't seem to make any difference where the source text comes from, in fact, even a multi-line region marked and sent that already appears in the process buffer (that doesn't contain `^M`) will have them when sent.

(**Note** the source text for the process-send-region will always come from a Emacs buffer, process-send-string, when multi-line will be from the Windows clipboard interface to the killring, or again from an Emacs buffer to killring.)

I should also add that the incoming text to the buffer is parsed by a `after-change-functions` hook (to do some colorisation based on input) so a last resort I'd do an additional `regexp-replace-in-string` on this incoming text as part of that hook function, I'd like to avoid that because it seems *wrong*, but I'll add it as a hacky solution if nothing else works.

#### Addendum

I updated the encoding settings for the buffer and the process to use `utf-8-dos` instead of `utf-8-auto` and the `^M`'s  vanished.

So in the buffer setup part of my app, I did...

```
(switch-to-buffer "sock-buffer")
(set-process-coding-system (get-process sock-process) 'utf-8-dos 'utf-8-dos)
(set-buffer-file-coding-system 'utf-8-dos nil)
(set-buffer-process-coding-system 'utf-8-dos 'utf-8-dos)
```

Then reduced this to just...

```
(switch-to-buffer "sock-buffer")
(set-buffer-process-coding-system 'utf-8-dos 'utf-8-dos)
```

And everything worked fine.

Comment: Please note the update, I've refined the question to the specific use case, with a process buffer, in this case the `dos2unix` approach is not relevant, however, I am able to process this text as it's inserted using emacs-lisp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because those files are in DOS/Windows line endings. You can use C-x [Enter] f unix [Enter] to convert them to the Unix encoding.

`^L` is a page break. I've seen them some times to separate different parts of source code (for old-fashioned listings in a text printer), or in text documentation to insert an actual "new page" command.

As of the update, [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Input-to-Processes.html) you can see that you have to select `set-process-coding-system` to the correct coding system.

Comment: FYI this is text sent to the `process-send-region` from any buffer in Emacs or to `process-send-string` via the windows clipboard.

Comment: Updated. Seems that you have to explicitly set the process encoding.

Comment: @Diego, I'll try `set-process-coding-system` first.

Comment: I `set-process-coding-system` to `'utf-8-auto` with no luck.

Comment: Could you try `utf-8-dos` or `utf-8-unix` and see if this changes anything?

Comment: I've already updated my process hooks to use a `regexp-replace-in-string`, but I'll give that a shot as an experiment.

Comment: I changed all the encodings relevant to the process and the buffer to `utf-8-dos` and it all worked, thank you, I've added more detail to my question text.

Comment: Minor nitpick: `^L` is a form feed (page break), not a line break.

Comment: @Porculus: Ah, yes, sorry for the mistake on ^L. Changed.

Answer (score 1):

Alternately to the `dos2unix` approach, you could use one of the MULE commands in Emacs, or (my favorite), since these characters are mistakenly treated as part of the text, you can replace them using the command to replace a string in the text: M-% C-q C-M RETURN

M-% is the query-replace command.

C-q means "let me type the next character without interpreting it as the RETURN key".

Comment: @slomojo If you do not want to do this interactively use `replace-string` instead of `query-replace`. Did you read the answer before copy-pasting your comment?

Comment: I'll have a look at the `replace-string` method of doing this after I've tried `set-process-coding-system`.

Comment: Because the process-buffer has an `'after-change-functions` hook, I needed to do the replace as a `regexp-replace-in-string` - this is what I suspected I'd need to do, I was just hoping there was an encoding setting I could've used to avoid this overhead. - I'll give Diego's encoding methods a try before marking the 'correct' answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you see those because of the inconsistencies in your newlines (e.g. windows newlines vs *nux ones), you should probably try [dos2unix](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/dos2unix1.html)