# ^M Character showing in clojure slime-repl

Tags: emacs, clojure, slime, termination

Each `(println...)` in my code results in a terminating ^M character appearing in the REPL.  I have a `lein swank` running in a separate window, and I've connected via `M-x slime-connect`

I think this might be the same issue as [Emacs showing ^M in a process buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120054/emacs-showing-m-in-a-process-buffer) but I haven't tried that fix yet.

I've tried changing end-of-line style to unix/dos/mac, and followed some of the other prescriptions I've found online, but I think most of those have to do with actually replacing the ^M either in the file or in the buffer, or writing some elisp which I think is probably overkill.  This really should be a check-box someplace, if not literally at least conceptually.

I'm using Emacs 24 + clojure mode + slime + swank on Win7 x64.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This method worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/750933

Basically just add this code to your .emacs:

```
(defun remove-dos-eol ()
  "Do not show ^M in files containing mixed UNIX and DOS line endings."
  (interactive)
  (setq buffer-display-table (make-display-table))
  (aset buffer-display-table ?\^M []))

(add-hook 'slime-repl-mode-hook 'remove-dos-eol) ;Remove ^M from clojure repl in windows
```